# Neural network having suspiciously bad results

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, time-series

I am playing around with the Keras library, trying to predict a timeserie and getting very bad results, I would like to know why the neural network can't handle even a simple scenario. My (engineered) data look like this:

(The **pattern is very simple** - result has exactly the same value as the feature, there are 10000 lines like this)

```html
dataPointIndex,feature,result
0, 1, 1
1, 1, 1
2, 0, 0
3, 1, 1
4, 1, 1
5, 1, 1
6, 1, 1
7, 0, 0
8, 1, 1
9, 0, 0
10, 1, 1
...
```

My Keras code:

```html
TIMESERIES_LENGTH = 10
TIMESERIES_SAMPLING_RATE = 1
TIMESERIES_BATCH_SIZE = 16
TEST_SET_RATIO = 0.2
VALIDATION_SET_RATIO = 0.2

data = pd.read_csv("data/" + csv_path)
x = data.ix[:, 1:2]
y = data.ix[:, 2]

test_set_length = int(round(len(x) * TEST_SET_RATIO))
validation_set_length = int(round(len(x) * VALIDATION_SET_RATIO))
x_train_and_val = x[:-test_set_length]
y_train_and_val = y[:-test_set_length]
x_train = x_train_and_val[:-validation_set_length].values
y_train = y_train_and_val[:-validation_set_length].values
x_val = x_train_and_val[-validation_set_length:].values
y_val = y_train_and_val[-validation_set_length:].values
x_test = x[-test_set_length:].values
y_test = y[-test_set_length:].values

scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(x_train_and_val)

train_gen = keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    length=TIMESERIES_LENGTH,
    sampling_rate=TIMESERIES_SAMPLING_RATE,
    batch_size=TIMESERIES_BATCH_SIZE
)

val_gen = keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(
    x_val,
    y_val,
    length=TIMESERIES_LENGTH,
    sampling_rate=TIMESERIES_SAMPLING_RATE,
    batch_size=TIMESERIES_BATCH_SIZE
)

test_gen = keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(
    x_test,
    y_test,
    length=TIMESERIES_LENGTH,
    sampling_rate=TIMESERIES_SAMPLING_RATE,
    batch_size=TIMESERIES_BATCH_SIZE
)

model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(TIMESERIES_LENGTH, 1)))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_gen,
    epochs=20,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=val_gen
)

plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.ylabel('accuracy/loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['training accuracy', 'validation accuracy', 'training loss', 'validation loss'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Results:

[image]

I have tried `LSTM` layers, but they perform similarly badly.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure your generator is outputting correctly? Try `x,y = next(train_gen)` and print.

Comment: That produces an error:
TypeError: 'TimeseriesGenerator' object is not an iterator

Comment: Ok, then `x,y = train_gen[0]`.

Comment: You are to be on the right track probably, I get:

`(Pdb) x,y = train_gen[0]
(Pdb) x
array([[[1.],[1.]], [[1.],[0.]], [[0.],[1.]]])
(Pdb) y
array([0., 1., 1.])`

That seems wrong, the features and results do not correspond at all.

Comment: If you have 10000 lines like this, the first column `dataPointIndex` will go from 0 to 9999. That is probably skewing the data heavily. Can you normalize this column to go from 0 to 1 and then try again?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar I don't think that's the case because the network don't work with the first column at all, see `x = data.ix[:, 1:2]` line at the beginning

Comment: @DanielMöller, do you think I am initializing the generator wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator` expects the y (`y_train` in my example) to be shifted by one compared to X (`x_train` in my case).

Your input data should be in such a shape that the particular subsequence of X ending at index `n` predicts value at index `n + 1` in your y. My original mistake was that it predicted value at index `n`.

Thanks to [Daniel Möller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2097240/daniel-m%C3%B6ller), for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

What is the mean value of the target data? Is it zero? From my experience, the default configuration of NN does not have a constant value which can be obtained by having last layer with affine or linear activation function.

Comment: The mean of both feature and result set (they are the same) is 0.5045